# Circular checkbox

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

I have this piece of code in an ASP.NET MVC application:

```
 @helper ApplicationStatus(string controlName, string source, string filterAction, string control = null)
{
    <div name="@controlName">

        <p style="font-size:20px">
            Application Status
            </p>
            <div ng-repeat="it in (@source)">
                <label class="label label-success">{{it.name}} <input type="checkbox" ng-model="it.check" /></label>
                <br />
            </div>

            <br />

            <button ng-click="">
                Reset
            </button>


            <button ng-click="@(filterAction)">
                Filter
            </button>
</div>
```

I want to give to the checkboxes a circular shape, how can I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Awesome Bootstrap Checkbox`:

**[Demo](http://flatlogic.github.io/awesome-bootstrap-checkbox/demo/)**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>
                        Circled
                    </legend>
                    <p>
                        <code>.checkbox-circle</code> for roundness.
                    </p>
                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-circle">
                        <input id="checkbox7" class="styled" type="checkbox">
                        <label for="checkbox7">
                            Simply Rounded
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="checkbox checkbox-info checkbox-circle">
                        <input id="checkbox8" class="styled" type="checkbox" checked="">
                        <label for="checkbox8">
                            Me too
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/y0L0hpja/)